# How can I concatenate a list of 2d numpy arrays into a 3d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I tried a lot but none of the `concatenate` or `vstack` works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `np.array`?

```
np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

makes a 2d array by concatenating 2 1d arrays (lists)

Similarly

```
np.array([np.ones(3,3), np.zeros(3,3)]]
```

should produce a (2,3,3) array.

An newish `np.stack` function gives you more control over which axis is added.  It works by expanding the dimensions of all input arrays by one, and concatenating.

You can expand the dimensions yourself, e.g.

```
In [378]: A=np.ones((2,3),int)
In [379]: B=np.zeros((2,3),int)
In [380]: np.concatenate([A[None,:,:], B[None,:,:]], axis=0)
Out[380]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
In [381]: _.shape
Out[381]: (2, 2, 3)
```

The key things to understand are:

- matching dimensions of the inputs - they have to match on all but the dimension that is being joined
- expanding the dimensions of inputs as needed.  To concatenate 2d arrays to form a 3d, the 2d's have to expand to 3d first.  That `None` or `np.newaxis` trick is especially valuable.
- concatenate along the right axis.

`stack`, `hstack`, `vstack` etc all facilitate this, but a skill numpy user should be able to work directly with `concatenate`.  Practice with small samples in an interactive session.

```
In [385]: np.array((A,B)).shape
Out[385]: (2, 2, 3)
In [386]: np.stack((A,B)).shape
Out[386]: (2, 2, 3)
In [387]: np.stack((A,B),axis=1).shape
Out[387]: (2, 2, 3)
In [388]: np.stack((A,B),axis=2).shape
Out[388]: (2, 3, 2)
```

If the arrays differ in shape, `np.array` will create an object dtype array

```
In [389]: C=np.ones((3,3))
In [390]: np.array((A,C))
Out[390]: 
array([array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]),
       array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])], dtype=object)
In [391]: _.shape
Out[391]: (2,)
```

`dstack` (and `stack`) will have problems with different size arrays:

```
In [392]: np.dstack((A,B,C))
....
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Comment: I've tried `np.array()` but that returns me a numpy array with shape `(n,)`, while each element within that is another numpy array.

Comment: Then your `n` arrays must differ in shape.  It is creating an object array.  What's the shape of your arrays?  I don't see how `dstack` would work.

Comment: I didn't realize that it at that time! I finally found some of my numpy arrays are not with the same size. Thanks for your answer so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use np.dstack, documentation can be located here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html

```
import numpy as np

l1 = []
# create list of arrays
for i in range(5):
    l1.append(np.random.random((5, 3)))

# convert list of arrays into 3-dimensional array
d = np.dstack(l1)

d.shape #(5,3,5)
```